Очистить xml от тегов
Такой вопрос, есть лента rss, через requests и beutifulSoup вытаскиваю текст новостей в виде:
> &amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;text-align:
> justify;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;К майским праздникам
> столица Чувашской Республики заметно преобразилась. Наведение порядка
> на улицах города, на объектах внешнего благоустройства выполняется в
> рамках поручений временно исполняющего полномочия главы города
> Владимира Доброхотова. &amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
> &amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;text-align:
> justify;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Чебоксары хорошеют, и основная заслуга в
> этом принадлежит службам городского хозяйства. Работы ещё
> продолжаются, но большая часть сделана в короткие сроки, за месяц
> после окончания зимы. Все службы отработали в период межсезонья
> добросовестно: без выходных, с продленными рабочими сменами, по
> некоторым направлениям - в круглосуточном режиме.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
> &amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;text-align:
> justify;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Конструктивные задачи всем профильным
> предприятиям временно исполняющий полномочия главы города Чебоксары
> &amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;Владимир Доброхотов&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;
> поставил заблаговременно. И это дало свои результаты.
> &amp;laquo;Исполнение контролирую лично, по факту, во время ежедневных
> объездов&amp;raquo;, - комментирует Владимир
> Анатольевич.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt; &amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;text-align:
> justify;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;object
> width=&amp;quot;300&amp;quot; height=&amp;quot;150&amp;quot;
> type=&amp;quot;image/jpeg&amp;quot;
> class=&amp;quot;tinymce_object_gallery&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;div
> class=&amp;quot;photo-gallery&amp;quot;
> data-albumid=&amp;quot;545f4e63-9461-4bfe-ac65-3c2289f4c0ef&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/object&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
> &amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;text-align: justify;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Вклад
> &amp;laquo;Дорэкса&amp;raquo; - чистые дороги, тротуары, остановочные
> площадки и павильоны, барьерные ограждения, колесоотбойники,
> восстановленные и покрашенные придорожные объекты благоустройства,
> проведённый сезонный ремонт дорог.&amp;nbsp;На сегодняшний день АО
> &amp;laquo;Дорэкс&amp;raquo; выполнен первый цикл уборки смета по
> основным магистралям, службы эксплуатации перешли на второстепенные
> дороги. С улиц вывезено более 13 тыс т смета.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
> &amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;text-align:
> justify;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Полностью завершена мойка всех остановочных
> павильонов (их в городе 446) и колесоотбойников.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
> &amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;text-align: justify;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;На
> завершающей стадии мытье ограждений (всего к мойке запланировано 39
> тысяч погонных метров конструкций), ведется их поэтапная
> покраска.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt; &amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;text-align:
> justify;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Приведение в надлежащее состояние рекламных
> щитов, урн &amp;nbsp;тоже включено в ежедневный график работ
> дорожников.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt; &amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;text-align:
> justify;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Что касается ямочного ремонта проезжей
> части, то по поручению &amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;Владимира
> Доброхотова&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt; увеличена ежедневная выработка по
> этому направлению: продлены рабочие смены, усилены бригады. С середины
> апреля в качестве материала используется горячий асфальт - с его
> применением устранены дефекты общей площадью около 2 700 кв.
> м.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt; &amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;text-align:
> justify;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;object width=&amp;quot;300&amp;quot;
> height=&amp;quot;150&amp;quot; type=&amp;quot;image/jpeg&amp;quot;
> class=&amp;quot;tinymce_object_gallery&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;div
> class=&amp;quot;photo-gallery&amp;quot;
> data-albumid=&amp;quot;8e6173fe-82a4-4c96-a61b-446620276c2c&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/object&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
> &amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;text-align:
> justify;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Чебоксарцы приходят на помощь городским
> службам. Сегодня сотрудники городских предприятий, служб, предприятий
> присоединились к Всероссийскому субботнику. Чистыми стали территории у
> парков, скверов и аллей, рядом с гаражными формированиями и у жилых
> кварталов. Спасибо большое всем, кто не остался в стороне, откликнулся
> на призыв принять участие в экологических мероприятиях, ваши усилия
> замечают гости столицы Чувашии и туристы.&amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
> &amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;text-align:
> justify;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;object width=&amp;quot;300&amp;quot;
> height=&amp;quot;150&amp;quot; type=&amp;quot;image/jpeg&amp;quot;
> class=&amp;quot;tinymce_object_gallery&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;div
> class=&amp;quot;photo-gallery&amp;quot;
> data-albumid=&amp;quot;8280c97b-a559-4214-9182-be9961e178fc&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/object&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
> &amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;text-align: justify;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;На
> проезжей части центральных дорог бригады АО «Дирекция гаражных
> хозяйств» наносят разметку &amp;ndash; на разделительные осевые и
> пешеходные переходы. Работы производятся как устойчивым
> термопластиком, так и краской.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
> &amp;lt;p&amp;gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;object
> width=&amp;quot;300&amp;quot; height=&amp;quot;150&amp;quot;
> type=&amp;quot;image/jpeg&amp;quot;
> class=&amp;quot;tinymce_object_gallery&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;div
> class=&amp;quot;photo-gallery&amp;quot;
> data-albumid=&amp;quot;aadddb31-777e-4f72-81e2-075d15f5a5a8&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/object&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
> &amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;text-align:
> justify;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;nbsp;В канун Первомая в городе
> продолжаются работы по приведению в порядок памятников и мемориальных
> комплексов, задействованы работники и техника АО &amp;laquo;Инженерная
> защита&amp;raquo;, АО
> &amp;laquo;Зеленстрой&amp;raquo;.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt; &amp;lt;p
> style=&amp;quot;text-align: justify;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Улицы города
> накануне майских уже обрели по-весеннему праздничный вид: на кольцевых
> развязках, у подножия монумента Матери-Покровительницы, в мемориальном
> комплексе &amp;laquo;Победа&amp;raquo; расцвели тюльпаны,
> разделительные полосы, столбы освещения, остановочные площадки
> украшены флаговыми композициями.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
> &amp;lt;p&amp;gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;

Как избавиться от всех этих тегов в тексте?
Собственно сам код:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import string
from datetime import datetime

rss_url = 'https://gcheb.cap.ru/rss?type=actual'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) '
                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get(rss_url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, features='lxml-xml')
articles = soup.findAll('item')
news = []
for a in articles:
    title = a.find('title').text
    pub_date = datetime.strptime(a.find('pubDate').text, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
    description = a.find('description').text
    full_text = a.find('yandex:full-text')
    print(full_text)


пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Попробуйте import html; html.unescape(...)

@aleksandrbarakin извиняюсь, исправил )

@CrazyElf к сожалению не помогло (
